# Ionicframework, back-button not working when video

Tags: ios, angularjs, back-button, ionic-framework

I'm developping an app with Ionic, and I have to display some video in playlist (I hoste them), so no Youtube player.
I use videoJS with plugin "videoJSPlaylist" : when a vdeo is finished, the next one play aotomatically, and I made "next" and "back" button to navigate in the playlist.

I had to remove the to make it work, otherwise it was not working. I have an issue on IOS where the back button is not working in the navbar. On the Chrome emulator and real android phone, the issue does not exist. 
Maybe someone has a hint?

index.html :

```
...

<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content drag-content="main.dragContent">        
        <ion-nav-bar back-button-type="button-icon" back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back"animation="nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c"></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right-ios7"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>

    <ion-side-menu side="left" is-enabled="isLeftMenuEnabled"> 
       ......
    </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

My html with video :

```
<ion-view title={{title}} hide-back-button="false" id="sequence">

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="videocontent">
            <video  id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-playing vjs-fullscreen" preload="auto"  controls data-setup="{}" width="auto" height="auto"></video>

            <button type="button" ng-click="prev()" class="controls-prev">Previous</button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="next()" class="controls-next">Next</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug with Safari? check that you have history of previous view. aka: `$rootScope.$viewHistory.backView != null`

Comment: ok, There is a problem with the playlist plugin apparently : 
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.player.playlist')'

Gonna try to fix this and retry on an IPhone

Comment: @MaximShoustin found a little mistake in the code but still does not work. Ios open the video with quicktime and I still cannot back to previous view when video is loaded

Comment: Hi! I have a similar issue, for me the back button is not working anymore after I displayed some ads from a native advertisement provider (its a video ad from Flurry). As soon as there is a video, the back button stops working. It seems like there is some `onPause` event listener that removes the back button functionality...